# How do I achieve this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, adapter

I'm trying to create a soundboard which looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/466fa8248aafe3232036b5586c070d30
What is the best way to achieve this?
Currently I'm trying it with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:text="Kohle song"
                android:id="@+id/ojeangelasong"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:onClick="kohlesong"
                android:layout_columnWeight="300"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"/>

            <Button
                android:text="Zum \nVideo"
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:onClick="kohlesongLink"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />
            <Button
                android:text="Zum \nVideo"
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:onClick="shooterkingLink"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:text="Roboter song"
                android:id="@+id/neulandBtn"
                android:onClick="roboter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="300"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:text="Zum \nVideo"
                android:id="@+id/Button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:onClick="roboterLink"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Zum \nVideo"
                android:id="@+id/Button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:onClick="remixLink"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:text="Gronkh Remix"
                android:id="@+id/zusammenschnittBtn"
                android:onClick="remix"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


            <Button
                android:text="Remix vorschlagen"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/soundvorschlagen"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                android:onClick="soundvorschlagen"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/soundvorschlagen"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />

            <Button
                android:text="Shooterking"
                android:id="@+id/autotuneremix"
                android:onClick="shooterking"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But I think this is not so professional.

Comment: Will the Layout be Dynamic or Static? (Will data inside the grid change?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:text="Button"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Button"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:text="Button"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:text="Button"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:text="Button"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A smaller but more complex way is to use on LinearLayout in your main xml file and create another xml which contains two buttons. And then display the respective buttons by inflating the second xml using [Inflate through databinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean,%20android.databinding.DataBindingComponent)). passing attatchToParent to true to display them one above the other.

And then show last button below the LinearLayout in first xml.

Answer (score 1):

**try this code **

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="song 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="song 1"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="song 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="song 1"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="song 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="song 1"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="song 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="song 1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"/>
```

**i hope this work for you**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout and then insert it in 5x horizontal layout. Each parameter "layout_weight" set to 3. Then, four of the top insert 2x Button and set each property to "match_parent". Then the properties of the button set the "layout_weight" to the left at 10, and the right to something about 15, so that it looked like you want to. In the properties of the lowest lying button set "match_parent."
At the end of course, set the rest of the properties according to your own discretion.
I think it will help.